# iphone: addTarget selector options

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is it possible to include the touches NSSet in the selector?

something like this:

```
[bookCoverImage addTarget:self action:@selector(dragBegin:withTouches:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters on button action:@selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716633/passing-parameters-on-button-actionselector)

Comment: Or, if you need drag functionality, try using a UIGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for that. As explained in [the documentation,](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) an action in iOS can have the form:

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

The event includes the set of touches, so there's no need to pass the touches as a separate parameter. To get the touches, just say:

```
[event allTouches];
```

or, perhaps more often:

```
[event touchesForView:theViewInQuestion];
```