# calling selector with arguments

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a method:

```
-(void)pickTheQuiz:(id)sender etat:(int)etatQuiz{
   //i need to get the etatQuiz value here    


}
```

and somewhere in my code, i call the method above like this:

```
int etat_quiz=4;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickTheQuiz:etat:)withObject:etat_quiz forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When doing so, i got error:

```
Receiver type UIButton for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'addTarget:action:withObject:forControlEvent
```

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)pickTheQuiz:(id)sender etat:(int)etatQuiz{


    NSLog(@"The part number is:%i",((UIControl*)sender).tag);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass the argument like this.Instead of that you can set the "etatQuiz" as the tag of your button.And can access it in your selector.
eg:

```
button.tag = etatQuiz;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickTheQuiz:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)pickTheQuiz:(UIButton *)sender {
   int value  = sender.tag;


}
```

Comment: and if i want to pass more than one information? for example 2 tags. thnx in advance.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716633/passing-parameters-on-button-actionselector this link

Answer (score 2):

You are using addTarget wrong, you should do:

```
addTarget:self action:@selector(pickTheQuiz:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```

And add the variable for example in the tag of the button

Comment: I got expected ':' when compiling using your solution, why the `::` are used?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solutions is to add the integer variable as the button's `tag` property. You can then retrieve it by using `((UIButton *) sender).tag`;

```
button.tag = 4;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickTheQuiz:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in `pickTheQuiz:` method:

```
int etatQuiz = ((UIButton *) sender).tag;
```