# UIScrollVIew View

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, icarousel

I'm using `iCarousel` as a slot machine, for those who doesn't know `iCarousel` it is a `UIScrollview` with  (paged, scrolling views). So in my app, I scroll it, then when it stops it shows the Image(Result) for 3 seconds, then a button pop-ups, if you press the button, it will delete the View(Image Result) then Rotates again.

Here is my way of deleting my carousel view:

```
    NSInteger CurrentImage = carousel.currentItemIndex;
    [carousel removeItemAtIndex:CurrentImage animated:YES];
    [images removeObjectAtIndex:CurrentImage];
```

But then when the `carousel.numberOfItems` has 1 item left, it doesnt scroll, instead its just stuck there.

So I made a way to make it scroll even it has only 1 Item(index) left.

I inserted it with the last index, so I tried this:

```
[self.carousel insertItemAtIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

(but doesnt work)

then I tried another:

```
int lastObject = [images objectAtIndex: ([images count]-1)]
[self.carousel insertItemAtIndex:lastObject animated:NO];
```

(still doesnt work)

and also this:

```
int count = [images count];
[images objectAtIndex:count - 1];
```

(still no luck)

Am I doing wrong? or What are other ways?
Or can I just duplicate the last View? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:** 
Methods

```
     - (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        if ([images count] == 1 || [self.carousel numberOfItems] == 1)
            return 2;

        return [images count];
    }

    - (NSUInteger)numberOfVisibleItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        //limit the number of items views loaded concurrently (for performance reasons)
        return 7;
    }


    - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
    {

        if (index >= [images count] || index >= [carousel numberOfItems]) {
            index = 0;
        }

        NSDictionary *obj = [images objectAtIndex:index];
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[obj objectForKey:@"image"]];
        view.tag = index;

        return view;
    }


    - (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        //note: placeholder views are only displayed on some carousels if wrapping is disabled
        return 0;
    }


    - (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        //usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
        return 400;
    }

 - (BOOL)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel shouldSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    return 5;  
}   
    - (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        //wrap all carousels
        return wrap;
    }
```

Delete Method:

```
-(void) deleteItem{
    //Removes the object chosen 
    if (carousel.numberOfItems >= 1)
    {   
        NSInteger index = carousel.currentItemIndex;
        [carousel removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
        //[images removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        //[images replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
    } 

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand, you want to rotate an object with only one element in it?

Comment: hmmmm, something like that. or make the 1 element a duplicate then rotate it.

Comment: try if-else statement and when you have 1 element insert it twice, then you will have 2 elements and can rotate them. Just an idea

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, could you show me?

Comment: `if([images count]==1){
[self.carousel insertItemAtIndex:0 animated:NO];
[self.carousel insertItemAtIndex:1 animated:NO];
}else{
}` it's just a guideline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is make

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel*)carousel;
```

return always a value >1 (eg. 2); then make sure that

```
- (UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel*)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView*)view;
```

always returns a correct view for the minimum number of elements you return from `numberOfItemsInCarousel`.

Eg.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel*)carousel {
   if (numberOfViews == 1)
      return 2;
   return numberOfViews;
}


- (UIView*)carousel:(iCarousel*)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView*)view {

  if (index >= numberOfViews) {
      index = 0;
  }

  NSDictionary *obj = [images objectAtIndex:index];
  view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[obj objectForKey:@"image"]];
  view.tag = index;
  return view;
}
```

You should also make sure that the last element is never deleted of add some guards in the code above to manage the case when no elements are left.

Comment: well, I tried and it works; you will have some other issue preventing that from working. in any case, I modified a little bit the code so to make its integration with your code easier.

Comment: Ill post my code here like your code, can you kindly check it sir?

Comment: I'm really having problem with this part `numberOfViews`. I dunno if Im doing it right, if it should be `[images count]` or `carousel.numberOfItems`. please help sir. :(

Comment: I think that `[images count]` is ok. To move on, you should set a breakpoint in `numberOfItemsInCarousel` and `viewForItemAtIndex` and look at why they do not work as expected... maybe you have one image left in the carousel but `images` contains more elements, or I don't know what...

Comment: I was able to make it work, but it works only when view i loaded with 1 image, but when removing it doesn't, what can I do?

Comment: what do you mean: when removing it doesn't? if you remove the last image, what do you expect to see?

Comment: for example:when view LOADS(newly loaded) I have two images present, then I delete the result image then only 1 remains, it doesn't rotate. BUT,when view LOADS(newly loaded) then I only have 1 image present in my array, it rotates.

Comment: I have to admit that I have a pretty fuzzy view now... maybe you could post your full code for the delegate methods and how you deal with image deletion...

Comment: Your code seems ok. Could you try calling `loadUnloadViews` or `reloadData` after deleting a view when `carousel.numberOfItems == 1`? (or each time you delete). this could make it work, I hope...

Comment: the `loadUnloadView` can't be called on mine. only `reloadData` but, when reloadData is called, the last deleted item item is redisplay on the view. :(

Comment: Then it seems, that you did not update your data source. I think the only chance you have to fix this is by debugging into those methods and see what happens in actuality. Sorry I can't help further...

Comment: Thank you for the help. here is one of my bounty question, if you want to just take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200584/nsmutablearray-difficulty