# Comparing with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In my `Array 1`, which I loaded images from `NSDocumentDirectory`,  I loaded them and add a `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
self.images = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]]; 
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
        NSMutableDictionary *container = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [container setObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath] forKey:@"image"];
        [container setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"index"];
        [images addObject:container];
    } 
}
```

In my other array `Array 2`, I loaded them from the app.

```
    self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"01.jpg",@"02.jpg",@"03.jpg",@"04.jpg",@"05.jpg",@"06.jpg",@"07.jpg",nil];
```

I was able to add string to `Array 2` like this:

```
for (int x=1; x<8;x++) {
    // add as NSString
    [images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];

    }
```

And was able to compare `Array 2` like this:

```
   NSInteger index = carousel.currentItemIndex;
    if ([[images objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 1){
```

What I wanted to do, is to do it to `Array 1`.
I know `Array 1` has been already added with `NSNumber`, but Im kinda new to `NSMutableDictionary` so I can't do it the same as `Array 2`.

Can it be done the same as my `Array 2` or what is the other way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are adding dictionary as an object to array, watch my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Here you have the array of dictionaries, because you are adding the dictionary which has two objects with keys `image` and `index`

So, for retrieving the array of dictionaries,

just log it and see what happens

**Edit 2.0**

```
for(int i=0; i< [images count]; i++){
    NSNumber *num =[[images objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"index"];

    int index = [num intValue];

    NSLog(@"%d",index)
}
```

Comment: its value in the debugger is all (null)

Comment: My bad, i have given key value as **value**. Now i have edited, keep the key value as **index**

Comment: yup, already have change it. Its index wag logged. But how to compare it like the above I mention. I kinda confused with this dictionaries.

Comment: You have to retireve the objects in the dictionary according to its corresponding key value and compare it inside the for loop, because you are getting the values inside it

Comment: I was able to display it. But I need to compare its indexes the value in dictionary to a integer or string.

Comment: Check my edit now, in the index you will get your index value from dictionary and then just compare like if (index == 1)

Comment: still not working the way I wanted it to,like the above, but thanks for the tip. my `Array 2` was accurate. I can't make it like that.