# Passing 2 parameters into UIButton's action function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, selector

I have a `UIButton`,

```
-(void)backBtn:(NSString *)parentId lbltext:(NSString *)label
```

function will be fired when push the button,

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(backBtn:lbltext:) 
       withObject:par 
       withObject:title.text 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

I looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716633/passing-parameters-on-button-actionselector) question. But my fired function will change my button name, depends some functions with the parameters. So I can't create another class.

How can I make this code true?Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a delegate for this instead. Trigger the event in your own class and then send it using a delegate. Also, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is better, `UIControlEventTouchDown` will be triggered even if the user regrets its action (by moving the finger outside the button).

```
- (void) touchEvent:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondToSelector@selector(par:text)]) {
        [self.delegate par:something text:@"MyText"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I created the UIButton with code. So am I gonna put the touchEvent into the action:@selector?