# UiBarButtonItem selector.. on click crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am stuck in a small problem,

I dynamically create a UIBarButtonItem using this code..

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(didSelectPopitDownFromNavBar:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

and the selector method is this..

```
-(IBAction)didSelectPopitDownFromNavBar:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
```

so it gives a crash on click.. how can i pass this event..?

Comment: Always post the error message with such a question. Though in this case it was obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the parameters form part of the method signature, so your button would need to use:

```
@selector(didSelectPopitDownFromNavBar:event:)
```

but this probably isn't going to do what you want as the button will only expect to pass itself (as the `sender`).

Comment: wouldnt that be sending a nil event...?

Comment: Of course the other solution to this issue would be to change the method to `-(IBAction)didSelectPopitDownFromNavBar:(id)sender {`. In other words, drop the `event` parameter. This assumes the `event` isn't needed by the handler.

Comment: does it pass an event? Can't say I've ever tried with 2 params

Comment: @rmaddy.. event parameter is needed by the handler.. em using a library that needs it..

Comment: OK then Wain's answer is the proper solution.

Comment: @rmaddy yes exactly... just waiting for the timer to end for selecting the answer

Comment: On iOS, the event will be correctly passed as the second argument for control events.

Answer (score 2):

If your function was

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(didSelectPopitDownFromNavBar:)];
...
-(IBAction )didSelectPopitDownFromNavBar:(id)sender
```

It shouldn't crash, the problem is likely the selector isn't properly defined,

see this question - [Passing parameters on button action:@selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716633/passing-parameters-on-button-actionselector)