# Pass self.navigationController as a parameter in addTarget for UIbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have programatically added a `UIButton`, for which I require `addTarget`. The selector action is in another class. I have used the following code to do this.

```
UIButton *homeBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,32,32)];
homeBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[homeBtn addTarget:[myClass class] action:@selector(ButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView:homeBtn];

+(void)ButtonTapped:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"here");
}
```

This works just fine. But I need to use `pushViewController` in the class function for which I need to pass the `self.navigationController` to the function.

I tried using `homeBtn.nav = self.navigationController;`
but this gives an error `'Property nav not found on object of type UIButton *'`

Can anyone please help me and tell me how to pass the `self.navigationController` to the class function.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716633/passing-parameters-on-button-actionselector

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You are creating *static* (aka *class*) methods, this is indicated by the `+` in front of the method name `+(void)ButtonTapped:(id)sender`. In these methods you can not access instance variables or properties of the objects, since they are called on a *class* and not on an object.

Instead of making everything static, maybe try to create instance regular methods for what you want to achieve. An example could be:

```
[homeBtn addTarget:myObject action:@selector(ButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView:homeBtn];

-(void)ButtonTapped:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"here");
}
```

Here, `myObject` should be an instance of the class `myClass`.

Having this, you are allowed to access instance variables of the object that invokes the `ButtonTapped` method, so then you are allowed to use `self.navigationController`.

PS. Naming conventions in iOS are such that you start method names with lowercase letters and class names with uppercase letters, so for you it would be `MyClass` and `-(void)buttonTapped`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use the following line:

```
homeBtn.nav = self.navigationController;
```

You can subclass UIButton and add the property to it.

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *nav;

@end
```