# iOS - passing arguments in action:@selector()

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, action, selector

I'm adding a button to a UITableViewCell programmatically.  The method to be run when the button is pressed is `- (void) quantityDown:(id)sender rowNumber:(int)rowNum`, where `rowNum` is the row that the button appears in.

When adding the target to the button, Xcode autocompletes the following:

```
[buttonDown addTarget:self action:@selector(quantityDown:rowNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But no matter what I try, I cannot pass the row number into the method.  I assumed the pertinent portion of code would look like

```
action:@selector(quantityDown:rowNumber:indexPath.row)
```

but that doesn't do the trick.  I've seen other stuff like

```
action:@selector(quantityDown:)rowNumber:indexPath.row
```

and

```
action:@selector(quantityDown:rowNumber:)withObject:@"first" withObject:@"Second"
```

But neither work.  I don't need to pass a first argument, just the row number.  I've also tried defining the method like `- (void) quantityDown:(int)rowNum` and then writing the selector like:

```
action:@selector(quantityDown:indexPath.row)
```

but that also doesn't work.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716633/passing-parameters-on-button-actionselector) thread.  Will try it out.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  I set `buttonDown.tag = indexPath.row` and then within the method I can access it via `UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *)sender;` and then setting an integer to `clicked.tag`

Comment: You can't pass value in button click. possible ways are find value from button sender, or call another method on button click. 1st is the right method.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you make a `Custom UIButton class` and have the object as property?

See below.

**"MyButton.h"**

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@property(nonatomic, strong)MyClass *obj;
@end
```

**"MyButton.m"**

```
#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now assign `MyButton class` to your actual button in the cell/ or initialize the custom button instead of normal `UIButton class` and assign the object directly.

And in your `IBAction` where `sender=MyButton`

```
- (void) quantityDown:(id)sender{
   MyButton *btn  = (MyButton *)sender;
   //You get the object directly
   btn.obj;
}
```

Doing it this way you can actually access as many properties you want easily. And its useful in other implementations too.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice solution.  If I needed more data than just the row number, this would definitely be the way I'd go.  The quick fix that I found is working for now, but it might not hold up to the rigors of everyday use.  Great solution again!

Answer (score 4):

Button can carry only one input so keep your sender and `rowNum` same so that it can be handled easily
In cell for row method.

```
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
b.tag = indexPath.row;
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(quantityDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Your method

```
 - (void)quantityDown:(id)sender  
    {    
       NSLog(@"%d", sender.tag);  
    }
```

hope this will help...

Answer (score 1):

Set each button tag as `indexPath.row`. Then just declare the function:

```
- (void)quantityDown:(id)sender
```

In that method do this:

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
```

Add target like this:

```
[buttonDown addTarget:self action:@selector(quantityDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

From `btn.tag` you can get the row number. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Yep.  That's what I ended up doing, as mentioned in a comment on the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Yeah I see it now. May be I was busy in typing the answer.. :P