# Buttons in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableViewCell with a button inside it, when I press the button, it moves onto the next view, but I need to pass the index of the TableViewCell, but I cannot find this because it is NOT in DidSelectCellAtIndexPath, it is only the button that is pressable.

How do I find out the indexPath of the Button and why does it crash?

Comment: add tag ti that button and pass this tag !

Comment: you can get the index by using DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: See my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22827645/790842. You can create `NSIndexPath` as property and use it like it is described there.

Comment: Assign the index row as the tag of that button and later retrieve it when it's clicked

Comment: see the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504421/getting-row-of-uitableview-cell-on-button-press

Answer (score 0):

***A very Simple solution :-***

```
(void)btnAction:(id)sender
  CGPoint btnRectPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                   toView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:btnRectPoint]; // Here you can get your indexpath of table
NSLog(@"index.row=%d",indexPath);

}
```

Comment: this works and logs the index path, but then in prepareForSegue, if I try to pass the indexPath, to an IndexPath in ViewController2.h it crashes with "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: my code in prepareForSegue is
`-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    ViewController2 *view = [segue destinationViewController];
 
    view.indexPath = self.indexPath;
}`

Comment: it breaks on  `view.indexPath = self.indexPath`.  self.indexPath is assigned at the bottom of the -(void)btnAction:(id)sender

Comment: inside (void)btnAction:(id)sender......     self.indexPath = indexPath;

Comment: i have posted a code in separate question, will post link when it allows me to post the question. how do i initialized "self.indexPath" in ViewController2

Comment: Im in chat, you around?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol and implement the delegate method in your `UIViewController`. Now when you are clicking on button inside `UITableViewCell`, you can pass the cell object itself as parameter to that delegate method.

```
-(void)protocolMethod:(id)sender {  
    [self.delegate delegateMethod:self];  
}
```

and in your `UIViewController`, you can get the index path of this cell from your table view.

```
-(void)delegateMethod:(MyCustomCell*)cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.objTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```