# Detecting From which Cell , UIButton was pressed in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two custom `UItableViewCell` with Same `UIButton` , How to determine from Which Cell `UIButton` is called ?

P.S. I Don’t want To use two different methods.

> cellForRowAtIndexPath Method.

```
if (indexPath.row==1) {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @“CustomeCell1“;

                            NewsFeedCell1 *cell = (NewsFeedCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
cell.btnPrivacy.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.btnPrivacy addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPrivacyClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
else
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomeCell2”;

                            NewsFeedCell2 *cell = (NewsFeedCell2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
cell.btnPrivacy.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.btnPrivacy addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPrivacyClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

> Button click Methods.

```
-(IBAction)btnPrivacyClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Privacy Clicked at : %ld",(long)sender.tag);

    // Here Determine From Which Cell UiButton Is Clicked.
    NewsFeedCell1 *cell = (NewsFeedCell1 *)[self.HomeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]];
```

Comment: See my answers here 1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22827645/790842 and here 2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30029818/790842. It will surely help. Cheers

Comment: If you mean which _type_ of cell (class NewsFeedCell1 or NewsFeedCell2), use `isKindOfClass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// *** Use Following code to detect `Cell` ***
CGPoint buttonPosition = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Throw some lights on this code. It will  give NSIndexPath Of UiButton.

Comment: @Naeem First line finds buttons position in given UITableView, next line it finds IndexPath for given position on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set tag for cell.btnPrivacy.tag=indexPath.row;

and in button action you will get button btnPrivacy tag i.e sender.tag which is cell index.

Try with this.

Comment: Please Read the question carefully, i have already set the Tag to UiButton

Comment: I think you have added this later, I am not able to saw at time of my comment.

Comment: Yes i have edited the question , but my question is to determine from which cell UIButton is Clicked ?

Comment: Yes, you can get it from above code,just add if condition to check tag 1 for cell1 and other tag for other cell2.

Comment: I have to determine row also , so i can;t assign static tag to UIButton

Comment: I think this is the same, setting indexPath.row as tag give you specific row.which is index of row in table. Also please brief your question if possible.

Comment: I have already specified in my question that i want to get from which cell button was pressed.