# iOS - Open Apple Maps with latitude and longitude directions

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

I am developing an application needs to open an Apple Maps session, and pass in latitude and longitude coordinates to get directions to that location from a users current location.

I know this can be done in google maps which I am already doing, but when attempting to open the URL in Apple Maps it just opens the place not the directions from a users current location to their destination.

Here is the URL scheme I have been using:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?ll=(someLatitude),(someLongitute)
```

Code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://maps.apple.com/?ll=\(locationLat),\(locationlong)")!)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should create an `MKMapItem` with your location then use the `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions()` method to open apple maps

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Try this code: [link](https://gist.github.com/matthijsotterloo/3def603f224d83f2b8f620f2174c535e)

Comment: Thanks, Matthijs, but I can already do that with the code that I have, just can not open directions.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38346083/762377) on how to use `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions`.

Answer (score 27):

Try this code, AppleMap will open up with the directions marked from device's current location to the location specified the coordinates.

```
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLat, currentLong)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
        mapItem.name = “Destination/Target Address or Name”
        mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions([MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
```

Answer (score 6):

try use

```
NSURL(string:"http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=\(currentLat),\(currentLong)&daddr=\(destinationLat),\(destinationLong)")!
```

with currentLat currentLong is users current location, and destinationLat destinationLong is destination location.

more parameters (ex: the transport type) look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [larva's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38365601/9024807) but I recommend you to use `"maps://"` URL scheme instead of `"http://maps.apple.com/"` to bypass opening Safari.

Like here:

```
URL(string: "maps://?saddr=\(currentLat),\(currentLong)&daddr=\(destinationLat),\(destinationLong)")
```